# How can I implement Google Search bar in HTML website?

Tags: javascript, html, json, web, search

Is that any possible way to implement Google Search bar in basic HTML website? I have tried it and succeeded, but I have this one issue - it keeps redirecting me to Google Search itself. I need to print the output and display it right on the website. In the form that the user inputs something and instead of redirecting to Google, it prints the first page of search results right on the website, for example underneath "Results" title.

Also, second question - how can I allow the user to download the page? For example, it prints the results and underneath is "Download" button that lets him save the page in whatever format they choose.

EDIT: So far I have come up with this code:

```
<html>
<p><strong>Google Search</strong></p>
<body>
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
<div style="border:1px solid black;padding:4px;width:20em;">
  <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0">
  <tr><td>
  <input type="text"   name="q" size="25"
  maxlength="255" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Google Search" /></td></tr>
  <tr><td align="center" style="font-size:75%">
  <input type="radio"  name="sitesearch" value="" />Web
  <input type="radio"  name="sitesearch"
  value="yoursite.com" checked /> Only this site<br />
  </td></tr></table>
  </div>
</form>
<p><br><br><b>Výsledky:</b></p>
<form method="get" action="test.html">
   <button type="submit">Download website</button>
</form>
<a href="test.html" download>Download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

You need to send the data somewhere — either with a regular form submission (as you have now, just not to Google) or (leaving basic HTML aside and adding JS) with Ajax.

Then you need to get some results — which means either finding an API which will provide the data you want or writing your own (and writing your own means also requires creating an index of the WWW). Either way, you need a programming language to do this.

Then you need to render the results. This means using a programming language to dynamically generate the HTML.

Comment: Thanks! And what would you suggest? Would be Python sufficient to do this?

Comment: For any server-side elements you can use whatever programming language you like (unless you are limited by your hosting service and can't change it).

Comment: And do you have any particular API in mind? Also, I have checked and supposedly I need to create another website where the Google Search results will be processed, is that correct?

Comment: I am not aware of any APIs which provide search results. I'm pretty sure Google doesn't supply one. If you want to use Google results then you have to land people on Google's site with Google's advertising.